# How many ways to write N as a product of M integers?

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, combinatorics, number-theory

Given an integer *N*, count how many ways it can be expressed as a product of *M* integers > 1.

Input is simply *N* and *M*, and output is the total count of *distinct* integer groups. Meaning you can use an integer more than once, but each group must be distinct (`3 x 2 x 2` would not count if `2 x 2 x 3` is present).

**Constraints**

1 < *N* < 2<sup>31</sup>
1 < *M* < 30

**Examples**

Input `30 2` gives output `3`, since it can be expressed 3 ways:

```
2 x 15
3 x 10
5 x 6
```

Input `16 3` gives output `1`, since there's only one distinct group:

```
2 x 2 x 4
```

Input `2310 4` gives output `10`:

```
5 x 6 x 7 x 11
3 x 7 x 10 x 11
3 x 5 x 11 x 14
3 x 5 x 7 x 22
2 x 7 x 11 x 15
2 x 5 x 11 x 21
2 x 5 x 7 x 33
2 x 3 x 11 x 35
2 x 3 x 7 x 55
2 x 3 x 5 x 77
```

Input `15 4` gives output `0`, since it cannot be done.

**Rules**

Standard code golf loopholes apply, along with standard definitions for input/output. Answers may be a function or full program. Built-in functions for factorization and/or partitioning are not allowed, but others are fine. Code is counted in bytes.

Comment: What do you mean by partitioning ?

Comment: @Optimizer Grouping a list into nonoverlapping sublists. Some languages have this built in, such as [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html).

Comment: Is there a time limit? A particularly naive algorithm could take centuries for a large value of M. Simple things like noting there can only be one factor larger than sqrt(N) obviously help a lot.

Comment: @steveverrill Given the upper limit on *N*, there should only be 30 (prime) factors max, which speeds things up quite a bit. However, feel free to be naive. If your algorithm is not likely to provide an answer within a few hours, a well-explained proof of concept could help voters decide.

Comment: a built in which allows you to do cartesian product of two list is allowed ?

Comment: @Optimizer Yes.

Comment: I assume that 1 is not a valid factor?

Comment: @FUZxxl Correct, see the examples and the opening sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Pyth](http://pyth.herokuapp.com) - <strike>24</strike> <strike>23</strike> <strike>22</strike> 21 bytes

Not a complicated solution. Will be golfing more. Just takes cartesian product of lists and filters. Same strategy as @optimizer (I'm guessing because of his comment, didn't actually decipher that CJam) Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for 2 bytes and trick with M.

```
Ml{m`Sdfqu*GHT1G^r2GH
```

Defines a function `g` with args `G` and `H`

```
M                    function definition of g with args G and H
 l                   length of
  {                  set (eliminates duplicates)
   m                 map
    `Sd              repr of sorted factors so can run set (on bash escape ` as \`)
    f                filter
     q      G        equals first arg
      u*GHT1         reduce by multiplication
     ^     H         cartesian product by repeat second arg
       r2G           range 2 to first arg
```

Worked on all test args except last, was too slow on that one but there is no time limit given.

Comment: Input is fine in that format.

Comment: Pyth golf tip: if you get 2 arguments, it is usually shorter to use `M` which defines the function `g` of 2 arguments, `G` and `H`. This is what I get for this: `Ml{msdfqu*GHT1G^r2GH`. Always nice to see another Pyth user :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman updated thanks for the tip.

Comment: This seems to give an incorrect answer for the input `72 3`, which returns 5, but there are in fact 6 answers, `(2, 2, 18), (2, 3, 12), (2, 4, 9), (2, 6, 6), (3, 3, 8)`

Comment: @isaacg oh ok, I'll revert it back to my 21 char version. I didn't think summing it would work but it seemed to, so i'll go back to repr. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: The above comment should have said `(2, 2, 18), (2, 3, 12), (2, 4, 9), (2, 6, 6), (3, 3, 8), (3, 4, 6)`.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 59

```python
f=lambda N,M,i=2:i<=N and f(N/i,M-1,i)+f(N,M,i+1)or-~M==N<2
```

We count up potential divisors `i`. With the additional argument `i` as the lowest allowed divisor, the core recursive relation is

```python
f(N,M,i)=f(N/i,M-1,i)+f(N,M,i+1)
```

For each `i`, we either choose to include it (possible as a repeat), in which case we divide the required product `N` by `i` and decrement `M`. If we don't, we increase `i` by 1, but only if `i<N`, since there's no use checking divisors greater than `N`.

When the minimum divisor `i` exceeds `N`, there's no more potential divisors. So, we check if we've succeeded by seeing if `M==0 and N==1`, or, equivalently, `M+1==N==1` or `M+1==N<2`, since when `M+1==N`, the mutual value is guaranteed to be a positive integer (thanks to FryAmTheEggman for this optimization).

This code will cause a stack overflow for `N` about 1000 on most systems, but you can run it in [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/) to avoid this. Moreover, it is extremely slow because of its exponential recursive branching.

Comment: I think you can use `-~M==N<2`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I thought that would give false positives, but indeed it works, thanks to the joint constraints on `M` and `N`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 67

```
f=->n,m,s=2,r=0{m<2?1:s.upto(n**0.5){|d|n%d<1&&r+=f[n/d,m-1,d]}&&r}
```

Actually reasonably efficient for a recursive definition. For each divisor pair `[d,q]` of n, with `d` being the smaller one, we sum the result of `f[q,m-1]`. The tricky part is that in the inner calls, we limit factors to ones greater than or equal to d so that we don't end up double-counting.

```
1.9.3-p327 :002 > f[30,2]
 => 3 
1.9.3-p327 :003 > f[2310,4]
 => 10 
1.9.3-p327 :004 > f[15,4]
 => 0 
1.9.3-p327 :005 > f[9,2]
 => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 48 bytes

This can be a lot shorter but I have added certain checks to make it work for decent number of `M` on the online compiler.

```
q~\:N),2>{N\%!},a*{_,2/)<m*{(+$}%}*{1a+:*N=},_&,
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: This is buggy. Try input `2 1`. Expected output: 1. Actual output: 0.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sigh. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL <del>456</del> 373

I'm sure this'll break when the inputs are even close to being large.

Thanks to @MickyT for helping to save a lot of characters with CONCAT and SELECTing instead of multiple SETs.

```
CREATE PROC Q(@N INT,@M INT)AS
DECLARE @ INT=2,@C VARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT COUNT(*)FROM # A1',@D VARCHAR(MAX)=' WHERE A1.A',@E VARCHAR(MAX)=''CREATE TABLE #(A INT)WHILE @<@N
BEGIN
INSERT INTO # VALUES(@)SET @+=1
END
SET @=1
WHILE @<@M
BEGIN
SELECT @+=1,@C+=CONCAT(',# A',@),@D+=CONCAT('*A',@,'.A'),@E+=CONCAT(' AND A',@-1,'.A<=A',@,'.A')END
SET @C+=CONCAT(@D,'=',@N,@E)EXEC(@C)
```

Comment: I'd like to upvote this, but I can't find a simple way to test it. Any ideas? Third-party confirmation that it works is good, too.

Comment: I get a couple of conversion errors we I run it (2012).  They appear to be from these statements `SET @C+=',# A'+@` and `SET @D+='*A'+@+'.A'SET @E+=' AND A'+(@-1)+'.A<=A'+@+'.A'`

Comment: You'll also need to fix `SET @C+=@D+'=@N'+@E+' SELECT @'`.  The `@N` is inside the quotes making it outside the scope when you execute `@C`.  Also I think you will end up counting duplicates

Comment: Now I've tested it on 2012. It should work.

Comment: Works good now :) A couple of place where you can shave some characters.  Try using `CONCAT` to build your strings.  Then you can drop the `CONVERT`s.  Try `SELECT @+=1,@C+=CONCAT(...),@D+=CONCAT(...),@E+=CONCAT(...)` in your `WHILE` loop.  Should save you a reasonable number

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ḍƇ`ḊœċP€ċ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjt5j7QkPd3QdnXykO@BR05oj3Y8ad/w/vFzp//9oYwMdBUMzHQUjY0MQyzT2f7SRjoKxjoIJEMUCAA)

Assumes that "Built-in functions for factorization and/or partitioning are not allowed" doesn't prohibit the `œċ` builtin, which is combinations with replacements. If this isn't allowed, we can use a Cartesian product builtin, which [is allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44983/how-many-ways-to-write-n-as-a-product-of-m-integers/210937#comment105858_44983), for 12 bytes: [`` ḍƇ`ḊṗṢ€QP€ċ⁸ ``](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjt5j7QkPd3Q93Dn94c5Fj5rWBAYAiSPdjxp3/D@8XOn//2hjAx0FQzMgNo39H22ko2Cso2ASCwA)

### How it works

```
ḍƇ`ḊœċP€ċ⁸ - Main link. Takes n on the left and m on the right
 Ƈ         - Filter the integers, k, between 1 and n where the following is true:
ḍ          -   Does k divide...
  `        -   ...n?
           - This gives a list of divisors
   Ḋ       - Remove the first value, 1
    œċ     - Take all combinations of length m, with replacement
      P€   - Take the product of each
        ċ⁸ - Count occurrences of n
```